# Non-uniform smoothing in bootstrapping uncertain data

Tags: bootstrap, uncertainty

Consider a dataset which has ~ $20$ measurements $m_i$ each of which has an associated uncertainty $\epsilon_i$.
There may be some outlier measurements which can have relatively low uncertainty.

I want to summarise the data and obtain a combined uncertainty. Due to the outliers, a weighted mean/median where the weights are given by $\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}$ may not be appropriate.

I have implemented the following bootstrapping approach:

For each bootstrap iteration

1. Resample from the measurements with replacement
2. For each measurement in the resampled data, add random noise to $m_i$ with the amount of noise determined by $\epsilon_i$
3. Record the median of the noisy, resampled points

Finally, calculate the mean and standard deviation of the calculated medians.

This is different from the standard smooth bootstrap because the noise applied is not uniform but depends on the uncertainty in the corresponding measurement.

This technique seems to be correct in the limit of $0$ uncertainty in the measurements (which would give the standard bootstrapping result) and in the limit of a single measurement (will give the measurement and uncertainty).

I was wondering if such a method is appropriate? I couldn’t find any literature using a non uniform smoothing in bootstrap and that made me doubt whether the approach can be justified.